# console.error: "react-native-maps" AirGoogleMaps dir must be added to your xCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-maps

> console.error: "react-native-maps" AirGoogleMaps dir must be added to your xCode project

I got this error when I am trying to test the example in `react-native-maps` module.

Github: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/tree/master/example

It is obvious that I should add the dir the to my Xcode project but I don't know how to add them.

May I have an example of adding dir to a Xcode project?

[image: image of error]

Comment: Have you followed these instructions https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md ?

Comment: I have tried those three options.

For the 1st option: I don't know how to add the dir to Xcode project.
For the 2nd option: I guess I followed completely
For the 3rd option: I cannot find the libAIRMaps.a file

Comment: The documentation is really bad. Perhaps this thread will help: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/693

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same error. No luck.. @ykn121 Were you able to build?

Comment: @ruyamonis346 Hi, I removed all the manual install before, and use pod install, then the problem is solved lol

Comment: @ ykn121 oh. I want to use GoogleMaps on iOS, so need to manually install the package.

Comment: @ruyamonis346 That's true. For manual install, there is `Option 2: CocoaPods`. I just followed it and it's done.

Comment: I have same issue..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AirGoogleMaps dir must be added to your xCode project to support GoogleMaps on iOS RN48](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188746/airgooglemaps-dir-must-be-added-to-your-xcode-project-to-support-googlemaps-on-i)

Comment: ever solved this? it was working fine for me until i got this seemingly for no reason..

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem using react native 0.61, the solution on my case was:
Stop the Metro Bundler, After that go to the pods directory:

```
cd ..
cd ios
```

Install again the pods:

```
pod install
```

Go to the project root:

```
cd ..
```

and run the project again `npx react-native run-ios`

This is the segment of my Podfile

```
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
```

Answer (score 0):

recently i had this issue, my problem solved with some changes on pod file.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'AppName' do
    pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
    pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'DevSupport',
    'BatchedBridge',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    ]

    pod 'GoogleMaps'  # Remove this line if you don't want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
    pod 'react-native-maps', path: '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
    pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: '../node_modules/react-native-maps'  # If you need GoogleMaps support on iOS

end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
            end
        end

        if target.name == "React"
            target.remove_from_project
        end
    end
end
```

also on your JS file you map tag must be something like this

```
<MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}                   
    style={styles.map}
    // provider='google'
    // mapType='standard'
    ...
>
```

notice that your pod file must be linked correctly. don't need to add anything manually.
you can remove your pod file and path with this commands

```
pod deintegrate
```

and

```
pod clean
```

and for install Cocoapods-Deintegrate Plugin and Cocoapods-Clean Plugin

Use this following command on your terminal to install it.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
```

Cocoapods-Clean Plugin

Use this following command on your terminal to install it.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-clean
```

hopefully this can help you.

Answer (score -1):

I just removed following prop in `MapView` component and it worked!

`provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}`