# AirGoogleMaps dir must be added to your xCode project to support GoogleMaps on iOS RN48

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, compiler-errors

I installed react-native-maps in my project in Android works perfectly but in I always the error appears, compiles well but has an error when executing in ios:

> console.error: "react-native-maps: AirGoogleMaps dir must be added to your xCode project to support GoogleMaps on iOS".

```
"dependencies": {

"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",

"react-native": "0.48.4",

"react-native-maps": "^ 0.17.1",

... }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had faced this problem a week ago, and I solved it yesterday.

First of all, My file structure like below and my version totally same as you.

```
MyApp--- ios
       |
       - android
       |
       - js- node-modules
           |
           - index.js
           |
           - etc...
```

Maybe it is little different with you, but just a file structure.

- I use pod to install react-native-maps and I never link with react-native.
  After you install react-native-maps, you can use iOS native map now.
  Make sure you already able to use iOS map after which I will take you through.
- In your xcode project left sidebar click right and click `Add files to "your project"` and choose node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios/AirGoogleMap
  [image]
- Go to your project => target => Build Setting => Header Search Paths
  and double click to add path `$(SRCROOT)/../js/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios`(this is my file structure) and turn non-recursive to recursive.

   If your file structure is following official like react-native, you should add path like this`$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios`.

That is done, I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it helped me a lot. regards

Answer (score 0):

Comment PROVIDER_GOOGLE and automatically react native maps will use iOS maps.

```
<MapView 
    style={styles.map}
   //provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
 />
```

Comment: This answer made my day. Thanks buddy

Comment: wow!! its really picked up iOS maps.!!