# react-native-maps: AirGoogleMaps dir must be added to your xCode project to support GoogleMaps on iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to use google maps on iOS and I get this error:

> react-native-maps: AirGoogleMaps dir must be added to your xCode project to support GoogleMaps on iOS.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B79Ha.png)

I'm using react-native.maps
 https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps

I followed the install instructions, in Android it worked perfectly but it doesn't in IOS

macOS: 10.14.1 (18B75)

```
dependencies {

"react": "16.5.0",

"react-native": "0.57.1",

"react-native-maps": "^0.22.1",

}
```

Comment: are you using cocoapods? did you really follow the instructions for iOS? they are not the same  and if you want to render google maps, it has extra steps.

Comment: @HelmerBarcos yes I'm using cocoapods, I added the AirGoogleMaps folder to my xcworkspace, added to mi Libraries folder the AirMaps.xcodeproj and added to my AppDelegate.m `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h> [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"_API_KEY_"];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AirGoogleMaps dir must be added to your xCode project to support GoogleMaps on iOS RN48](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188746/airgooglemaps-dir-must-be-added-to-your-xcode-project-to-support-googlemaps-on-i)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok I just had the same problem, so here is how i fixed it:

First follow this answer here:

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/693#issuecomment-262656417

Then you would need to go inside xcode > build settings > Preprocessor Macros > add HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS=1

P.S inside actual component i used

```
import MapView from "react-native-maps";

<MapView provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE} style={styles.map} />
```

my styles > map: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0 
  }

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: HI, the issue I'm having is there's no option for preprocessor macros, talkies of adding the value

Answer (score 7):

ADD THIS CONDITION TO YOUR <MAPVIEW

provider={Platform.OS === 'android' ? PROVIDER_GOOGLE : PROVIDER_DEFAULT}

Answer (score 3):

Or, if the provider isn't important for you, just remove following prop in `MapView`:

`provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}`

It solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Install the library react-native-maps. Follow the link instructions

```
https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md
```